# How to extract article in chinese

Tags: python, web-scraping, goose, python-newspaper

```
from newspaper import Article
import pdb
from unidecode import unidecode
def get_article_newspaper(url):
    article = Article(url,en='zh') # Chinese
    article.download();
    article.parse()# article.text if blank!
    print unidecode(article.text).replace('Image caption','')

url='http://www.tyfzw.cn/?sw=774&b=177%20'
get_article_newspaper(url)
```

This seemed the most maintained so tried. Also, tried goose and boilerpipe neither work.

Later want to translate also :

```
import goslate
def language_translate(text): #translates to language
    gs = goslate.Goslate()
    language_id = gs.detect('text')
    if language_id != 'en':
        text=gs.translate(text, 'en')
    return text
```